# How can I calculate the sum of the integers in a dictionary? Tried num = num + pair.Value but gives me total + 1 for some reason

Tags: c#

This is the method I have tried, but it gives me 1 more than it should be because I have the list of hashtags I am counting in notepad, there in one pair line and the last one says line `19993` but the program outputs `19994`.

```
private static void outputNumOfTotalTags(Dictionary<string, int> list, int numOfTags)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
    {
        numOfTags = numOfTags + pair.Value;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The total number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, although that is some awfully ugly code.  The bug is somewhere else.

Comment: o.k thanks how can I make it less ugly?

Comment: I agree that the bug is elsewhere.  As an aside, you can make this much prettier by using LINQ: var sum = list.Sum(x => x.Value);

Comment: Technically there is an extra `}`, but it's fine.

Comment: Someone's probably going to say Linq but this will probably be quicker. Although just iterating the Values would be neater.

Comment: I would eliminate the whole function and write it in one line, like James did below.  The specific things that I think are un-idiomatic about the function are:  Passing in `numOfTags` rather than writing a pure function to return the number of tags and doing output one level above.  Mutating the `numOfTags` argument within the function instead of using `Sum` or a temporary variable.  Writing `KeyValuePair<string, int>` instead of using `var`.  Camel-case function name instead of typical Pascal-case.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Linq is pretty darn efficient for Sum() since it doesn't use deferred execution.  I'd argue the increase in readability would edge out any performance loss.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare probably true. I quite like the readability of Linq sometimes. I thought that mquander's "awfully ugly" comment was a little on the harsh side. I've seen much uglier!

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Oh sure, as foreach loops go it's pretty benign.

Comment: I don't think it's that bad either.  I would not call an instance of a Dictionary "list" though.

Answer (score 0):

If numOfTags always starts at zero, don't pass it in.  To clean up the code, just use LINQ:

```
private static void outputNumOfTotalTags(Dictionary<string, int> list)
{
    // if you don't need a seed value, and just want the sum of list's values:
    var numOfTags = list.Sum(pair => pair.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("The total number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
}
```

Or, if you're using some seed value (as it appears from the method since you pass in a numOfTags to start) add it to the Sum():

```
private static void outputNumOfTotalTags(Dictionary<string, int> list, int numOfTags)
{
    // if you are preserving a "seed" value for numOfTags, do this:
    numOfTags += list.Sum(pair => pair.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("The total number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
}
```

As to the bug, it seems possible that you may have a starting value of 1 instead of zero.

Comment: @NullUserException: true...  was editing the original code a little too literally :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this...

```
private static void outputNumOfTotalTags(Dictionary<string, int> list, int numOfTags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The original number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
        //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list) == you don't need the pair.
        foreach (int Value in list.Values)
        {
            //numOfTags = numOfTags + pair.Value; == a change since you don't need the pair.
            numOfTags = numOfTags + value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The total number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
        //} == This closing what ?!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing in `int numOfTags` and incrementing it, is it possible you initialized `numOfTags` to 1 before passing it in? Make sure it is zero.

Unless you have a need to increment the existing `numOfTags` value, I would do without it and rewrite the method as follows:

```
private static void outputNumOfTotalTags(Dictionary<string, int> list)
{
    int numOfTags = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
    {
        numOfTags += pair.Value;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The total number of hashtags is: {0}\n", numOfTags);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was zero but my list of tags had a space in it where the line was empty I got rid of that and it's working. Pretty annoying been given a list with a gap in it been struggling with thsi for ages.

Comment: @user979236 sounds like you need to add some input validation to ignore blank entries.